# Is it possible to change user with Sublime SFTP plugin

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, sftp

I use Sublime SFTP plugin to connect to a server as user `my.name`.

When using Terminal (in ssh session) I have to change my role with `sudo -iu project.user` to be able to change/update project code.

Is there some trick that would let me change user through Sublime SFTP plugin so that I can update the code, as in "normal" SSH scenario where login user has granted permissions to change the code?

Comment: @Did you find a solution? I have the same issue

Comment: working solution is planned for future relese: http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=18866